# Why don't installation codec updates and ubuntu restricted extras include the libdvdcss files?

Tags: codecs

I think it's pretty strange that they're not included. This is one thing that will scare new users away.

Comment: A legal alternative for DVD playback would be the Fluendo DVD Player available for installation from the Ubuntu Software Center (currently priced at US$24.95). Click [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/fluendo-dvd) to install it.

Comment: On another side note, [Windows 8 no longer includes DVD playback by default](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8#Removed_features); it now has to be purchased separately to cover licensing costs. So, Ubuntu is not alone in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably [because of the legal issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libdvdcss#Distribution) around CSS, at least in some jurisdictions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main idea is that libdvdcss is free software, but illegal.  Ubuntu restricted extras is more the opposite, that the codecs are legal, but the software is non-free.